# Removing a node from the Cypher query result in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have the following cypher code:

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE toLower(n.name) STARTS WITH toLower('ja') 
RETURN n
```

This case-insensitive query returns all the nodes which their names start with the substring "ja". For example if I execute this in my db it will return ["Javier", "Jacinto", "Jasper", "Jacob"]

I need this script to also remove the unwanted nodes on this list, for example let's say that an array containing ["Jasper, Javier"] is sent to the data access layer indicating that those two nodes shouldn't be returned, leaving the final query result as follows: ["Jacinto", "Jacob"]

How can I perform this?

Answer (score 2):

If you know before making the query which items should be excluded you can say:

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE toLower(n.name) STARTS WITH toLower('ja') 
AND NOT (toLower(n.name) IN ['jasper', 'javier'])
RETURN n
```

Comment: you can also pass in that list as parameters.

Comment: Btw. for best performance, store the lower case variant in a property and index it. Then you get index support for both STARTS WITH and IN.

Comment: Supposing that I don't know the array length, how can I iterate through it to remove the nodes to be excluded?

Comment: I've never done that before, but it can be done in the host language I suppose, or better, as a query parameter (prefixed with `$`)

Comment: Using the `IN` operation, you don't need to explicitly iterate through the list, and therefore you don't need to know the length of the list.